# Session not working PHP

Tags: php, oop, session, authentication

The session is not getting created and keep getting redirected to login.php. Really don't understand why! I really need help :(

Here is my Session class:

```
class Session {

    private $logged_in=false;
    public $user_id;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();
    if($this->logged_in) {
      // actions to take right away if user is logged in
    } else {
      // actions to take right away if user is not logged in
    }
    }

  public function is_logged_in() {
    return $this->logged_in;
  }

    public function login($user) {
    if($user){
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $this->logged_in = true;
    }
  }

  public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->logged_in = false;
  }

    private function check_login() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
      unset($this->user_id);
      $this->logged_in = false;
    }
  }

}

$session = new Session();

?>
```

Here is a part of my Login page:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

  $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
    $found_user = User::authenticate($user_name, $password);

  if ($found_user) {
    $session->login($found_user);
    redirect_to("index.php");
  } else {
    // username/password combo was not found in the database
    $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
  }

} else { // Form has not been submitted.
  $user_name = "";
  $password = "";
}
```

And here is a part of the index.php:

```
if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php");
```

What I have tried:

I tried putting a session_start(); at the start no luck.
Looked for errors in all the code used in these pages.

Comment: why do you need a session class? and why do you have `session_start();` inside `__constract()`?

Comment: Could it be because i'm using a WAMP local server?

Comment: Nope.. session has nothing to do with the server.. Have you tried displaying the values of your session? Or at least instantiate a separate session(without the class) then output the values to another page and see if it really don't work?

Comment: I'm a beginner. I really don't know how to print_r a session.

Comment: And I added session_start(); inside __construct so it creates a session when its called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `session_start();` before the if statement in the login page.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem but I realized it was not a session that was not working. I was getting a "session already started" error after adding this function.

Answer (score 0):

because you try to use object from session that you didn't declared in login page

just do this in the login page and every thing will be fine

include "Sessionclass.php";
if you already did that , then you need to check the output of the 
$found_user = User::authenticate($user_name, $password);

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was a problem with my WAMP server. So, now I got Wamp 2.5 and am no more facing this problem.